# Finding all kinds of extensions referenced in a html file

Tags: html, regex, bash, unix, grep

Here is my problem statement :

*There is a folder with many html and text files. I need to recursively go through each one of them and find all kinds of file extensions referenced in these html/text files like .jpg, .tif, .png etc*

The problem is I don't have a defined list of the extensions I want to search for.

What would be the best way to achieve this using a shell script ?

Coming up with a Reg-ex which would essentially search for all occurrences of a dot followed by 3 or 4 letters, and filtering out the ones which end with a space or a comma, or a quote etc ??

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shell script to parse file name with regex, but straight forward version is pretty simple:

```
$ cat *.{txt,html} | grep -oP '\b[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}\b' | awk -F. '{ print "." $(NF) }' | sort -u
```

For recursive search:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.html' -exec grep -oP '\b[A-Za-z0-9_.]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}\b' {} \; |  awk -F. '{ print "." $(NF) }' | sort -u
```

Comment: I think the filenames the O.P. is looking to parse are inside the html and txt files that `ls -1` would return. Good luck.

Comment: I am looking to parse inside the html and text files not the file name . Please advice.

Comment: I built the whole logic in java, I was looking to have a shell script instead with a regex to filter it out

Comment: I will share the specifics and my findings after verification. I need to extend that command to recursively search in all directories

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47363/discussion-between-hackmabrain-and-alex)

Comment: Amazing Alex ur recursive one worked like a charm. I learnt something today